# PHP/MySQL - Unable to submit values after 1 record inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I'll preface by stating that I am a bit new to PHP and MySQL.  I am attempting to write my session variables to a MySQL database.  I thought that I had performed this correctly after I was able to use my HTML form to submit the first record, but I am unable to submit additional records.  Only one record shows in my database, and any attempts to submit new records do not error out, but instead just simply do not appear in my database.

My forms are carried across multiple pages, so I'll include my PHP code:

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","mypassword");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

  mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO imaging (os,MAC,Model,AntiVirus,Browser,Email,Connectivity,Sound,Ports) 
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['imaging2']."','".$_SESSION['imaging3']."','".$_SESSION['imaging4']."','".$_SESSION['antivirus']."','".$_SESSION['browser']."','".$_SESSION['email']."','".$_SESSION['connectivity']."','".$_SESSION['sound']."','".$_SESSION['ports']."')
  OR die("Could not update: ".mysql_error());

  mysql_close($con);

?>
```

My table name is: imaging

My columns in my database are as follows:

```
id - My primary key field set to Auto_Increment, type is int(11)
os - text
MAC - text
Model - text
AntiVirus - text
Browser - text
Email - text
Connectivity - text 
Sound - text
Ports - text
```

Since it worked at least one time, it seems obvious that this is a problem with the codes interpretation of my primary key field.

Any help is always greatly appreciated.  And hey, who knows?  Maybe it is just a matter of stepping away from the computer long enough to get my eyes uncrossed and clear again. :)

Am I missing a reference to my id field in my PHP code?

Comment: do a print_r($_SESSION); before you insert and make sure there are actually values there.  Also, just an fyi: I would keep all database fields lowercase and you should sanitize those inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really your code you have a problem with the call to `mysql_query`. As you can see by the syntax highlighting it is incorrect. You need an extra `")` at the end:

```
mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO imaging (os,MAC,Model,AntiVirus,Browser,Email,Connectivity,Sound,Ports) 
  VALUES ('".$_SESSION['imaging2']."','".$_SESSION['imaging3']."','".$_SESSION['imaging4']."','".$_SESSION['antivirus']."','".$_SESSION['browser']."','".$_SESSION['email']."','".$_SESSION['connectivity']."','".$_SESSION['sound']."','".$_SESSION['ports']."')
") or die("Could not update: ".mysql_error());
```

By the way, this code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Be careful!

Comment: Maybe... if it is I will delete this answer.

Comment: I think he's right...the actual SQL syntax is correct.  I tried several times and got it to work.  INSERT INTO imaging               
(os,MAC,Model,AntiVirus,Browser,Email,Connectivity,Sound,Ports) 
VALUES ('V','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')

Comment: It wouldn't insert anything if that was the case, but he says it's inserting a single field. Probably just empty values.  If he has them set to NULL in the database, they will be empty strings afterwards.

Comment: You were exactly correct!  I was missing the "); at the end of my query.  I love this site.  I usually try what I know (which admittedly isn't much) before posting, but you hit the nail on the head, Mischa.  Thanks everyone for the input!  I'm able to enter more than one field now.  And thanks for the tips about SQL Injection.  I have a lot to learn yet.

Comment: If you're just learning, i'd move on to PDO since mysql_ is on the way out anyways.  Much simpler if you start fresh, and a lot more secure for things like the SQL injection.

Comment: Agreed, +1. Also, hit up a framework like Kohana, it will help you along quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll definitely start checking out PDO and Kohana.